# How to get session variable in app.post request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, caching, redis

I would like to get the data from session variable (req.user.username) then use it for posting. I'm using passportjs as authentication. I'm using router. Here is my code:

```
router.use('/login', passport.authenticate("local-register", async (err, user, info) => {
      if (err) {
        return next('Error');
      }
      if (!user) {
        return next('Error'); 
      }
      req.user = user;
      return req.login(user, (error: Error) => {
        if (error) {
          return next('Error');
        }
        return req.session.save((erro: Error) => {
          if (erro) {
            return next('Error');
          }
          return next();
        });
      });
    })(req, res, next);)
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.user.username) // working just fine
});
router.post('/upload', async (req, res) => {
  const uploaderName = req.user.username // I'm getting undefined
  const upload = await database.query('INSERT INTO user WHERE username=$1', [uploaderName])

  console.log(uploaderName);
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally found the answer to the question. For those who will encounter the problem in the future. You just add the session middleware AGAIN on the top of the routes. If your routes are separated to the main server file.
/src/routes/routes.ts -> add again the middleware on top.

```
const app = router();
app.use(sessions) // -> right here you need to add the middleware again to //access the req.user session variable 
app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.user.username) // working just fine
});
app.post('/upload', async (req, res) => {
  const uploaderName = req.user.username // I'm getting undefined
  const upload = await database.query('INSERT INTO user WHERE username=$1', [uploaderName])

  console.log(uploaderName);
})
```

Comment: Do you have two different routers and added the session middleware only to one router? In that case the problem isn't reproducible. There is no router in the question.

Comment: I updated the question again. Would you mind explaining why this happens? why does express cant read the middleware created in main file in router file? This problem caught me off-guard I thought every middleware in the main file can be read from router file. Thank you for criticizing of my question.

Comment: Do you have one router for all routes or multiple routers? The question and answer are unclear. Are both routes registered on the same router?

Comment: Sorry for my bad english. Yes I have multiple routers. I have routers for login, home, register and others.

Comment: I can't see these multiple routers in the code in the question or in the answer, but that's an important part of the problem.